# automatically change my aperture for my lens sigma 24-70 f:2.8

Tags: lens

I used sigma 24-70mm f:2.8 with Canon 6d
I have problem in between clicking of shots.

in first shot no problem in second shot picture  result is dark as compare with first shot in 3rd 4th pictures going darker in every click and after 10-12 click my setting is back to first so please suggest me.
what can i do ...?

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand. Is anything else changing in the scene? What mode is the camera in? Does it always follow this pattern? Does it happen with other lenses or just this one?

Comment: Can you post some samples?

Comment: Have you checked to see if you have accidentally turned on *auto bracketing*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You noted that aperture is changing, could you confirm aperture change by visual (look into lens during shoots) and also by EXIF data? If aperture is changing itself without camera intervention it could be following:
1. damaged spring in aperture system, can be inspected, replaced...
2. broken flex cable. or Nearly broken and sometimes is conducting and sometimes not, could result in whatever behavior.
3.lens electronic have problem, can be measured.

Comment: yes bro this is aperture problem of lens because i used another lens for canon-24-70 f:4 and it's ok during shoot and i thing you are right about spring or flex cable problem. as soon as possible i m going to market to repairing of this lens and thanks again to reply me. Thanks

Comment: Canon EF lenses have no springs. The aperture diaphragm is controlled by a small servo motor that moves it in either direction as required.

Comment: I would be happy to help you with lens service too, but I dubt it woudl be worth of money to send lens to me and back to you then.
Yes Michael but he wrote that it is Sigma lens.